# Shopify Dawn - Default Collection Filtering

Tags: shopify

I have the following use case:

1. A product contains many variants. Jumper1 - Red, Jumper2 - Blue, Jumper3 - Green... Jumper2 - Red etc.
2. I have a jumpers collection which shows Jumper1, Jumper2. All good.
3. I now have a Red Jumpers Collection that I want to show Jumper1 - Red, Jumper2 - Red. Filters seem to do this in a really nice way. I set the colour filter to red and now all my red jumpers are showing.

How can this be implemented into a collection page? I could hardcode the collection query string into the navigation but this is not a solution suitable for SEO or getting to the collection via an external link.

Or is there a better way to achieve this within Dawn?

Answer (score -1):

You can add a rule to robots.txt to skip links containing query parameters - this way you would avoid custom implementation and at a low cost achieve what you need without impacting SEO.